# The Specific Vector Perpendicular to Three Other Vectors in 3-dimensional Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $a$, $b$ and $c$ are 3-dimensional vectors.
When $a$, $b$ and $c$ are linearly dependent to each other, does the vector which is perpendicular to $a$, $b$ and $c$ exist all the time?

I learned that if it exists, then $a$, $b$ and $c$ are linearly dependent to each other, but I can't decide if the converse proposition would be true.

Comment: English technicality: you wouldn't say "the" vector perpendicular to $a,b,c$ unless you were sure there is only one (which is false - there are infinitely many, all scalar multiples of each other).

Answer (score 1):

If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are linearly dependent, then one of them is a linear combination of the other two. Suppose, say, that $c$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Take a vector $d$ perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$. Then $d$ is also perpendicular to $c$.

Comment: This answer is perfect. A more geometric way to think about it is the following. Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are not scalar multiples of one and other, together they define a two-dimensional plane. The claim that $c$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ is equivalent to the claim that $c$ is in that plane. The question now is: can you always find a vector that is perpendicular to this two-dimensional plane that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are in? Just by picturing a two-dimensional plane in 3D space in your head you can see the answer is yes.